# How come the switch in my idcheck code running instantly before I actually enter an input?

Tags: c++

You'll find the code below
Im not sure why this is happening, but I am still learning c++ so im not gonna be surprised if its something small and dumb lol

```
#include <iostream>

void idcheck();

int main(){

    bool houseID = 151;
    bool ID;

    int house1 = 1;
    int house2 = 2;
    int house3 = 3;

    std::cout << "*****Welcome to miniclean property managers*****\n";
    std::cout << "Please enter your airBnB's address: ";
    std::cin >> ID;

    if (ID = houseID)
    {
        idcheck();
    }
    

    


    return 0;
}

void idcheck(){
    bool code = 144794221;
    int checkC;

    std::cout << "Please enter code: ";
    std::cin >> checkC;

    switch (checkC)
    {
    case '144794221':
        std::cout << "Thankyou, your house code is 8868. Enjoy your stay!";
        break;
    
    default:
        std::cout << "Incorrect code, please try again";
        break;
    }
}
```

The code is meant to be able to be used to check into airbnbs with an access code, but the code is completely ignoring the switch and displaying this

*****Welcome to miniclean property managers*****
Please enter your airBnB's address: 151
Please enter code: Incorrect code, please try again

So im a bit confused, help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `if (ID = houseID)`... Remember the difference between `=` and `==`.

Comment: As for `'144794221'`, that's a multi-character literal. First of all, it's not an integer value, use `144794221` (without the quotes) for that. Secondly, multi-character literals are implementation defined, and are not portable.

Comment: `bool code = 144794221;` is the same as `bool code = 1;`. `bool` holds one of two values: `true` or `false`, which are equal to 1 and 0. I don't see a need for any `bool` variables in this code; it deals with integer values, so use `int` or `unsigned`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In main you have (with some other stuff)

```
bool ID;
std::cin >> ID;
```

So `ID` is declared as a boolean (true or false), and you read into, but you enter `151`, which is not a valid boolean.  Depending on your flags, `1` might be, but that will leave `51` to still be input.  Regardless, when you then call idcheck, it will either have `cin` in a fail state, or will have some data to read, so the `cin >> checkC` will return immediately.

Always make sure that your data input is in the form expected, and check cin to make sure there hasn't been an input failure.